# git add image is not pushed to server

Tags: android, git, git-push

I changed a drawable a png file after I edited with GIMP and added to Android Studio in res folder. On the emulator i can see it is changed. And i can see on bitbucket that is not changed although i send these commands

> git add -A #I tried also git add -u and git add .
>
> git commit -m "new button"
>
> git push -u origin master

my git status says that everything is updated. I understand that the way git works does not detect that i changed the file. I remember i did it something in few months ago without using rm but I cannot remember which command I used

Comment: did you add the image filename or folder in .gitignore by mistake ?

Comment: nope. I controlled as well. I resolved a similar situation few months ago, itiIs a command i have to pass with git add if I well recall but I do not remember which one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the --refresh and --force flags.

From the Git manual:

> --refresh 
>              Don’t add the file(s), but only refresh their stat() information in the index. 
>  
>   -f, --force 
>              Allow adding otherwise ignored files.

Comment: git add --refresh . && git add --force .

Comment: Now is working! thank you Makunha and welcome to Stack Overflow, I am proud I am the first person you helped. I am going to accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm in my experience that changing the name of my image on my local site and then adding and pushing the changes to Git caused the image to then show up on git's live page servers.

Thanks for the tip @trocchietto!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but I would not be happy to mark as answer. Just changed the name of the file, refactored the name, and added, committed and successfully pushed.

It works, but is not the command I launched few months ago